# What's the difference between WP 7.5 and WP8 development?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile

I am trying to start some mobile development adventure. The Windows Phone looks promising to me. But I don't want to take the wrong path.

So, what's the difference between WP7.5 and WP8 **from a developer's perspective**?

Will the skillset for WP7.5 still apply to WP8?

Answer (score 3):

Difference? Nothing, really. The IDE is now VS2012, and you need Windows 8. The Emulator is running Hyper-V, and is a lot faster.

If you make games, you'll be have to learn DirectX instead of XNA. But for regular apps, there's no difference to the development.

You can of course use C++/CX now, should you wish it, but in reality everything is still C# 5 and XAML.

My recommendations would be to continue learning WP7, C# and XAML. Read about the new features in C# 5, specially async programming, and learn how it can enhance your development.

Answer (score 2):

Right now we don't yet know the definitive details (unless someone with access to the preview SDK can expand on that) however it is unlikely that the basics will change too much.

Current standard WP7.5 apps should run on WP8 - Microsoft has said they will be centrally adjusting the apps for this compatibility.